# C# read every other excel row

Tags: c#, excel

I'm pretty new to coding, so this could be simple solution. I need to be able to read the odd rows of an excel file in C# and assign the cell values to unique variables. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are new, but usually when you ask questions you provide some context of the problem, what you have tried so far (code and or research), and what errors you have gotten. Remember to research first before asking :) https://coderwall.com/p/app3ya/read-excel-file-in-c

Comment: As a hint, figure out how to read every row in an Excel file.  Once you are able to do that, figure out how to throw out the even ones.

Answer (score 1):

I would try downloading the NuGet package [Closed XML](https://closedxml.github.io/ClosedXML/) it makes handling excel files easy.
They also have some easy [guides](https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml/wiki) to do what you need to do. I imagine your going to need a for loop and use there `IXLWorkSheet.Row()` method.